backspace issue in otp verification ios devices
 Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        CodeInput(
                            controller: _controllers[0],
                            focusNode: _focusNodes[0],
                            nextFocusNode: _focusNodes[1],
                            previousFocusNode: _focusNodes[0]),
                        SizedBox(width: 12.63.w),
                        CodeInput(
                            controller: _controllers[1],
                            focusNode: _focusNodes[1],
                            nextFocusNode: _focusNodes[2],
                            previousFocusNode: _focusNodes[0]),
                        SizedBox(width: 12.63.w),
                        CodeInput(
                            controller: _controllers[2],
                            focusNode: _focusNodes[2],
                            nextFocusNode: _focusNodes[3],
                            previousFocusNode: _focusNodes[1]),
                        SizedBox(width: 12.63.w),
                        CodeInput(
                            controller: _controllers[3],
                            focusNode: _focusNodes[3],
                            nextFocusNode: _focusNodes[3],
                            previousFocusNode: _focusNodes[2]),
                      ],
                    ),

class CodeInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final FocusNode focusNode;
  final FocusNode? nextFocusNode;
  final FocusNode? previousFocusNode;

  const CodeInput({
    required this.controller,
    required this.focusNode,
    required this.nextFocusNode,
    required this.previousFocusNode,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Focus(
      onKey: (node, event) {
        if (event is RawKeyDownEvent &&
            event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace) {
          if (controller.text.isEmpty && previousFocusNode != null) {
            previousFocusNode!.requestFocus();
            return KeyEventResult.handled;
          }
        } else if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
          // Check if the key pressed is a digit (0 to 9)
          final isDigitKey =
              event.logicalKey.keyId >= LogicalKeyboardKey.digit0.keyId &&
                  event.logicalKey.keyId <= LogicalKeyboardKey.digit9.keyId;
          if (isDigitKey) {
            if (controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
              nextFocusNode!.requestFocus();
            }
          }
        }
        return KeyEventResult.ignored;
      },
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 24,
        child: TextField(
          onTapOutside: (event) => focusNode.unfocus(),
          controller: controller,
          focusNode: focusNode,
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
          maxLength: 1,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          showCursor: false,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23.3),
          autofocus: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: "\u25cb",
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
            counterText: "",
          ),
          onChanged: (value) {
            controller.text = value;
            if (value.isNotEmpty && nextFocusNode != null) {
              nextFocusNode!.requestFocus();
            } else if (value.isEmpty && nextFocusNode == null) {
              focusNode.requestFocus();
            } else if (value.isEmpty &&
                nextFocusNode != null &&
                previousFocusNode != null) {
              if (controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
                controller.clear();
              } else {
                // If the current input field is already empty, move focus to the previous field
                focusNode.unfocus();
                previousFocusNode!.requestFocus();
              }
            } else if (value.isEmpty && previousFocusNode != null) {
              // Handle backspace case to keep the focus in the current field
              focusNode.requestFocus();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );

We are implementing OTP verification on Android and iOS devices. On Android, the backspace/delete function works properly, but on iOS, it does not. Additionally, we have four input fields for the OTP. If the OTP is entered continuously, it works fine. However, if a wrong digit is entered, we cannot go back to correct it. Also, if the cursor is in the second input field and the third field is empty, the cursor won't move to the next input field automatically. How can we resolve these issues? we dont have cursor visible

You can try package pin_code_fields
It is very easy to implement
PinCodeTextField(
  length: 4,
  obscureText: false,
  animationType: AnimationType.fade,
  pinTheme: PinTheme(
    shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
    fieldHeight: 50,
    fieldWidth: 40,
    activeFillColor: Colors.white,
  ),
  animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade50,
  enableActiveFill: true,
  errorAnimationController: errorController,
  controller: textEditingController,
  onCompleted: (v) {
    print("Completed");
  },
  onChanged: (value) {
    print(value);
    setState(() {
      currentText = value;
    });
  },
  beforeTextPaste: (text) {
    print("Allowing to paste $text");
    //if you return true then it will show the paste confirmation dialog. Otherwise if false, then nothing will happen.
    //but you can show anything you want here, like your pop up saying wrong paste format or etc
    return true;
  },
)

